# Convert 3-Element List of Tuples to Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert this:

```
[(1, 'al', 10), (2, 'bob', 20), (3, 'cam', 30)]
```

to

```
{1: ('al', 10), 2: ('bob', 20), 3: ('cam', 30)}
```

I can do it this way:

```
list = [(1, 'al', 10), (2, 'bob', 20), (3, 'cam', 30)]
dict = {}
for i in list:
   dict[i[0]] = (i[1], i[2])
```

But that seems gross. There must be a better way with dict() and zip() or something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
>>> x = [(1, 'al', 10), (2, 'bob', 20), (3, 'cam', 30)]
>>> dict([(a, (b, c)) for a, b, c in x])
{1: ('al', 10), 2: ('bob', 20), 3: ('cam', 30)}
```

Passing in a list of 2-tuples to `dict()` will give a `dict` using the first item in the tuple as the key and the second item as the value.

Comment: The list comp is unnecessary `dict((a, (b, c)) for a, b, c in l)` will do the same job

Answer (score 1):

dict comprehension and tuple slicing!

```
>>> l = [(1, 'al', 10), (2, 'bob', 20), (3, 'cam', 30)]
>>> {t[0]:t[1:] for t in l}
{1: ('al', 10), 2: ('bob', 20), 3: ('cam', 30)}
```

this is good because it also allows for variable sized tuples.